ASP.NET Core 8 : singleton pattern with HttpContextAccessor does not work together
I'm developing an ASP.NET Core 8 application and using the singleton pattern for session management, but when I want to read the values, it displays null values!
Here you can see the code:
SessionSingleton.cs:
[Serializable]
public sealed class SessionSingleton : IDisposable
{
    #region Private Members
    private const string SessionSingletonName = "SessionKey_502E69E5-668B-E011-951F-00155DF26207";
    private static readonly object LockObject = new();
    #endregion

    #region Singleton
    private SessionSingleton()
    {
    }

    public static SessionSingleton Current
    {
        get
        {
            lock (LockObject)
            {
                string? value;
                SessionSingleton sessionSingleton;

                var session = CustomHttpContext.Current.Session;

                if (session == null)
                    return null;

                if (session.GetString(SessionSingletonName) is not null)
                {
                    value = session.GetString(SessionSingletonName);
                    sessionSingleton = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SessionSingleton>(value!)!;
                }
                else
                {
                    sessionSingleton = new SessionSingleton();
                    var sessionText = JsonSerializer.Serialize(sessionSingleton);
                    session.SetString(SessionSingletonName, sessionText);
                }

                return sessionSingleton;
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public properties
    public string Name { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Dctor
    public void Dispose()
    {
         // HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionSingletonName] = null;
         // HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove(SessionSingletonName);
    }
    #endregion
}

CustomHttpContext:
public static class CustomHttpContext
{
    private static IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor = new HttpContextAccessor();

    public static HttpContext? Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (_httpContextAccessor == null)
                _httpContextAccessor = new HttpContextAccessor();

            return _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        }
    }
}

HomeController:
public partial class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        SessionSingleton.Current.Name = "Test";

        var value = SessionSingleton.Current.Name; // value is always null

        SessionSingleton.Current.Name = "Test2";

        value = SessionSingleton.Current.Name;// value is always null

        return Ok(true);
    }
}

All code like serialization and deserialization works fine, but why is value always null in HomeController?
Please suggest a way to store the user's information and to be able to access that information simply during the execution of the program by the user.

First of all, I don't think you are supposed to instantiate the HttpContextAccessor by calling new, but rather get it from DI.
Second, why are you not using the standard DI mechanism that ASP.NET Core already provides? This unnecessary part about locking the singleton could be resolved by one line builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISessionManagement, SessionManagement>();
Third: What is the pupose of this code?

Because I want to read its value from Session and it is not possible with this method

Finally, after various checks, I changed my code as below and it solved my need well.
After many investigations, I realized that for any reason, using the combination of Singleton with HttpContextAccessor will not lead to the desired result.(Maybe because of the logic of asp.net internal middlewares)
For this reason, I tried to meet my needs in a way that is both clean and extensible code.
Therefore, I used the interface and put my fields in it so that I can easily implement it and also use the dependency injection feature.
ISessionHandler
public interface ISessionHandler : IDisposable
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

SessionManager
internal sealed class SessionManager : ISessionHandler
{
    #region Private Members

    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly ISession _session;

    #endregion

    #region Ctor
    public SessionManager(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        _session = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Session!;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Dctor

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _session.Clear();
    }

    #endregion


    public int UserId
    {
        get => _session.Get<int>();
        set => _session.Set(value);
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get => _session.Get<string>();
        set => _session.Set(value);
    }
}

Then I created a static helper class to set and get information of the session.
SessionExtension
internal static class SessionExtension
{
    public static void Set<T>(this ISession session, string key, T value)
    {
        session.SetString(key, JsonSerializer.Serialize(value));
    }
    public static T Get<T>(this ISession session, string key)
    {
        var value = session.GetString(key);
        return value == null ? default! : JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(value)!;
    }

    public static void Set<T>(this ISession session, T value)
    {
        var key = GetKey();
        session.SetString(key, JsonSerializer.Serialize(value));
    }
    public static T Get<T>(this ISession session)
    {
        var key = GetKey();
        var value = session.GetString(key);
        return value == null ? default! : JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(value)!;
    }

    private static string GetKey()
    {
        var frame = new StackTrace().GetFrame(2);
        var instanceName = frame?.GetMethod()?.DeclaringType?.Name;

        var methodName = frame?.GetMethod()?.Name;
        var key = $"{instanceName}_{methodName}";
        return key.Replace("_set", "").Replace("_get", "");
    }
}


program.cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISessionHandler, SessionManager>();
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = ".Test.Session";
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseSession();

app.UseRequestLocalization();
app.MapDefaultControllerRoute();

app.Run();

And finally, as shown in the code below, I used it in my controller and wherever needed.
LoginController
public partial class LoginController : BaseController
{
    public LoginController(ISessionHandler sessionHandler)
    {
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        SessionHandler.Name = "Test";

        var name = SessionHandler.Name; // It's OK


        return Ok();
    }
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

First of all consider using tools provided by the ASP.NET Core to manage session - see the Session and state management in ASP.NET Core docs.
As for the IHttpContextAccessor usage, it is not how it works. You should avoid using it by default - it is for quite specific use cases (and has some performance cost). IHttpContextAccessor is handled by the DI and is handled by ASP.NET Core itself. You (might) need to register it in the DI:
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

And then resolve where it is needed. See the Access HttpContext from custom components section of the docs.
But in case of the controller action this is not needed, just use this.HttpContext to access the current context.

I use the Singleton pattern, for this reason, Microsoft's documentation does not work for me.
Also, due to the use of the Singleton Pattern and because it is a static class, it is not possible to inject HttpContextAccessor into the SessionSingleton class.

@MohamadGhafari "I use the Singleton pattern" 1) why? Arguably you should not 2) even you want/need to use it - use singleton's via DI (i.e. via AddSingleton)

Because I want to read its value from Session and it is not possible with this method

@MohamadGhafari in general you should not use singleton pattern in modern ASP.NET Core. Why exactly you need/want tomuse it here?

Because I want to use the properties of Singleton class simply and clearly.
Also involved in the complexities of using
HttpContext.Session.SetString() and HttpContext.Session.GetString()
If you have a better suggestion, please guide me
